# XQuery: Calculate the diffrence of two days

Tags: xquery

I was looking for a way to calculate the duration between 2 xs:date objects.
I got a working solution using the div approach that I found [here](http://www.datypic.com/books/xquery/chapter20.html) [image]
Im not happy with that solution. Maybe there is a better approach doing it...

```
let $today := current-date()
let $date:= xs:date("2019-05-20")
(: will return 3 :)
return ((xs:dayTimeDuration($today - $date) div xs:dayTimeDuration("PT1M")) div 60) div 24
```

Basically I get the minutes passed by and than calculate the hours from the diffrence, which will be used to calculate the days that passed by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compute the difference in days, it should suffice to compute the difference between the two `xs:date`s and then you can divide that result by a duration of one day:

```
let $today := current-date()
let $date:= xs:date("2019-05-20")
return ($today - $date) div xs:dayTimeDuration("P1D")
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcoA

Comment: That approach feels much better, I knew there had to be something :) 
Is there any documentary that you can suggest for xQuery beginners?

Comment: The page you used it part of the online sample of Priscilla Walmsley's book XQuery that is a good read as an introduction to XQuery 3, I think you can either buy it as an e-book or as a normal book. And the Altova guys have some material online for free https://www.altova.com/training/xquery3, https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3. And of course XPath and XQuery are public W3C recommendations easily accessible so trying to look in there can't hurt although obviously specs can be a bit lengthy and too detailed for a beginner to start with.